# Do reproductive organs function before puberty?

Tags: human-biology, sex, sexual-reproduction

Testis means one of the two male reproductive glands that produce spermatozoa and secrete androgens.

Ovary means one of usually two organs that produce oocytes and secrete oestrogen and progesterone.

Do these organs function before puberty?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not functional before puberty.

For males:

> Most males begin puberty between the ages of 9 and 14, but commonly puberty will begin around 12 years old. When the human body reaches a certain weight (which differs among individuals), the hypothalamus releases gonadotropin-releasing hormone. This hormone signals the pituitary gland to release the two hormones that begin the onset of puberty: leutinizing hormone and follicle-stimulating hormone.7 **In males, these hormones stimulate activity in the testes, which start to produce the male sex hormone testosterone and begin spermatogenesis. Spermatogenesis is the process of sperm production**.

<sub>[source](https://sexinfoonline.com/going-through-male-puberty/) (warning: contains NSFW drawings and images)</sub>